# C# - Func<Tinput1,Tinput2,Toutput> could not be assigned with the delegate function, when the Tinput, Toutput is generic

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           function4<int, double, string>();

        }

        public static string function1(int i, double d)
        {

            return "return_string";
        }

        public static void function4<D1,D2,D3>()
        {
           // Func<D1, D2, D3> f1 = function1; //does not work? Any idea why?
            Func<int, double,string> f1 = function1; //works fine
            string s = f1(10, 20);

        }

    }
}
```

Why function1 could not be assigned as `Func<D1, D2, D3> f1 = function1`?
But it works fine when `Func<int,double,string> f1 = function1`.
I am trying to make the parameter as more generalized.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the generic parameters on `function4` is that you can invoke it with different parameter types, such as:

```
function4<string, string, string>();
function4<int, char, string>();
```

But clearly, `function1`'s method signature is not compatible with the above examples.  The compiler can't assume that `function4` will only ever be invoked this way: `function4<int, double, string>();`, so it gives you an error to protect you against the other possible invocations with different parameter types.

If you only ever want to invoke `function4` with `<int, double, string>` as the generic parameter types, then you don't need generics at all in the first place.

Comment: Thanks.Later on, to function4 i might be passing double, int, string or float, double, string etc and develop over it. So, is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: The syntax of Func<TInput,TInput.....,TOutput>.. In that case, since it takes the Template, why it does not allow the different datatypes to be passed?

Comment: Exactly. so imagine you invoke `function4<double, int, int>();`.  Then `Func<D1, D2, D3> f1 = function1;` would effectively mean: `Func<double, int, int> f1 = function1;`.  But `function1` is ***only*** compatible with `int, double, string`, because `function1` is not defined with generic types.  Therefore, the compiler can't allow that.

Comment: Ok, then why Func takes Templates? If this is not possible, any idea, how i can do this?

Comment: I can't really answer that, because I don't really understand your use case.  The only thing clear to me is why the compiler is unhappy with your current code.